# Change the position of Excel rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have a controller that takes the data displayed on my page and creates an Excel spreadsheet using it.

Here is the `Excel` controller **without** the retrieving of data (since it's not relevant to my problem) :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Excel(string user)
{
    var products = new System.Data.DataTable("Activity");                        

    products.Columns.Add("Project", typeof(string));

    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var jour in ListDaysOfMonth)
    {
        products.Columns.Add(jour, typeof(int));
        counter++;
    }

    List<string[]> lstInts = new List<string[]>();

    foreach (Project p in lp)
    {             
           products.Rows.Add(p.Name, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);             
    }

    int i = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 0;
    foreach (string[] tab in lstInts)
    {
        while (tab[z] != "")
        {
            products.Rows[i][y] = tab[z];
            y++;
            z++;
        }            
        i++;
        y = 1;
        z = 0;
    }                  

    var grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = products;
    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=Activity_{0}.xls", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return View("Excel");
}
```

And here's is an example of an excel spreadsheet created through this process :

[image]

But here's my problem :

Since I add the columns with `products.Columns.Add` I can't find a way to create said columns further in the grid so that I can add new information on the top left corner of it.

Per example, having the currently existing columns starting at cell E9 so that I can have information such as the creation date and the employee on the top left of the spreadsheet.

What should I change in order to do it?

Here's what the desired output looks like :

[image]

Comment: you can add creation date, employee columns just as you add the `Project` column outside the loop.

Comment: I don't want to add additional columns to it. I simply wish to add some information on the top left corner and move the columns further.

Comment: I guess I couldn't understand what you mean by top-left corner and move columns further. what are you referring as top-left column? can you make a image of desired output?

Comment: Absolutely, I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if best, but you can try

```
        var employee = "Employee Name";
        var month = "October";
        var year = "2015";

        htw.WriteLine("Year: {0}<br/>Month: {1}<br>Employee: {2}<br/>",year,month,employee);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
```